# Netsuite SSv1 Replace Filters of Saved Search with Filters From Another Saved Search

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I need to replace the filters of every search I loop through (selectedSearchId variable in loop) with the filters of a generic search (searchGen). I am successfully looping through my array and getting the IDs, so I just need to apply the filters. Any help?

```
var searchGen = nlapiLoadSearch('item','customsearch_ca_export_detail_search__38'); //loads a generic search 

    //TODO: get filters from searchGen

    for (var i = 0; i<selectedMarketsArray.length; i++){

            //TODO: replace filters of each selectedSearchId with filters from searchGen

            var selectedSearchId = marketplaces[selectedMarketsArray[i]].searchId;

            nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','selectedSearchId',selectedSearchId);

    }
```

Side note, I spent a couple weeks going back and forth with Netsuite reps with this same issue in SSv2 to only find that it was a bug that needs to be fixed. This is why I am re-writing in v1.

I am still new to suitescript (especially SSv1) so any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

- Jesse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did end up figuring this out, if anyone is interested. I use the "getFilters()" and "setFilters()" functions as such:

```
 var searchGen = nlapiLoadSearch('item','customsearch_ca_export_detail_search__38'); //loads a generic search 

    searchGenFilters = searchGen.getFilters();

    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','searchGenFilters',searchGenFilters);

    if(updateSearches){

        for (var i = 0; i<selectedMarketsArray.length; i++){

                //TODO: replace filters of each selectedSearchId with filters from searchGen

                var selectedSearchId = marketplaces[selectedMarketsArray[i]].searchId;

                nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','selectedSearchId',selectedSearchId);

                var selectedSearch = nlapiLoadSearch('item',selectedSearchId);

                selectedSearch.setFilters(searchGenFilters);

                nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','Selected Search Filter',selectedSearch.getFilters());

                selectedSearch.saveSearch();


        }

    }
```

Hope this is helpful!

- Jesse